# Select columns from second subquery if first returns NULL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-11

I have two queries that I'm running separately from a PHP script. The first is checking if an identifier (group) has a timestamp in a table.

```sql
SELECT
    group, MAX(timestamp) AS timestamp, value
FROM table_schema.sample_table
GROUP BY group, value
```

If there is no timestamp, then it runs this second query that retrieves the minimum timestamp from a separate table:

```sql
SELECT 
    group, MIN(timestamp) as timestamp, value AS value
FROM table_schema.src_table
GROUP BY group, value
```

And goes on from there.

What I would like to do, for the sake of conciseness, is to have a single query that runs the first statement, but that defaults to the second if NULL. I've tried with coalesce() and CASE statements, but they require subqueries to return single columns (which I hadn't run into being an issue yet). I then decided I should try a JOIN on the table with the aggregate timestamp to get the whole row, but then quickly realized I can't variate the table being joined (not to my knowledge). I opted to try joining both results and getting the max, something like this:

Edit: I am so tired, this should be a UNION, **not a JOIN**

sorry for any possible confusion :(

```sql
SELECT smpl.group, smpl.value, MAX(smpl.timestamp) AS timestamp 
FROM table_schema.sample_table as smpl
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT src.group, src.value, MIN(src.timestamp) AS timestamp 
     FROM source_table src
    GROUP BY src.group, src.value) AS history
ON
    smpl.group = history.group
        
GROUP BY smpl.group, smpl.value
```

I don't have a `SELECT MAX()` on this because it's *really slow* as is, most likely because my SQL is a bit rusty.

If anyone knows a better approach, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: Please share sample data in text format with your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
select mx.group,(case when mx.timestamp is null then mn.timestamp  else mx.timestamp end)timestamp,
(case when mx.timestamp is null then mn.value else mx.value end)value
(
    SELECT
       group, MAX(timestamp) AS timestamp, value
    FROM table_schema.sample_table
    GROUP BY group, value
)mx
left join
(
    SELECT 
         group, MIN(timestamp) as timestamp, value AS value
    FROM table_schema.src_table
    GROUP BY group, value
)mn
on mx.group = mn.group
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying! I made a mistake and edited the post to reflect this, but a Union is maybe more appropriate. Although I think your answer works, I'll try it out and let you know.